# Why fscanf() rounds number to integer?

Tags: c++

I'm using a sample function from tutorial [a link](https://github.com/huamulan/OpenGL-tutorial/blob/master/common/objloader.cpp) which read OBJ file for render by OpenGL.

I code my application in Qt 5.9.3 and use QML to make GUI. Application read data from .bt file (OctoMap) and viusalize them in subwindow. Unfortunatelly when I try to read the same model from OBJ my app doesn't show anything. When I use debug mode and check vectors then both (from bt and obj) are the same. Below are showed variables from OBJ file:

```
v -2.0868 -1.6868 4.680000
v -2.0868 -1.9132 4.680000
v -2.3132 -1.6868 4.680000
v -2.3132 -1.9132 4.680000
v -2.0868 -1.6868 4.520000
v -2.3132 -1.6868 4.520000
v -2.0868 -1.9132 4.520000
v -2.3132 -1.9132 4.520000
```

and info from debug mode:

```
vertices2   <36 elementów>  QVector<QVector3D>
    [0] @0x3257148  QVector3D
        xp  -2.0868000984191895 float
        yp  -1.6868000030517578 float
        zp  4.679999828338623   float
    [1] @0x3257154  QVector3D
        xp  -2.0868000984191895 float
        yp  -1.9132000207901    float
        zp  4.679999828338623   float
    [2] @0x3257160  QVector3D
        xp  -2.313199996948242  float
        yp  -1.6868000030517578 float
        zp  4.679999828338623   float
```

Vectors from Octomap are the same, so it should work correctly.
QOpenglShaderProgram which draw render model takes vectors' variables by pointer:

```
program1.setAttributeArray(vertexAttr1, vertices.constData());
program1.setAttributeArray(vertexAttr1, vertices2.constData());
```

Data from second vector are not visualised even if I'm not using first vector.
However I found one possible reasons of problem. When I try to print out variables by command std::cout then I get this output:

```
one: -2.0868 two: -2
one: -2.3132 two: -2
one: -2.0868 two: -2
one: -2.0868 two: -2
```

where one's are OctoMap vector two's are OBJ vector.
I create OBJ vector by function from turorial

```
bool openGLrenderer::loadOBJ(
    const char * path

){
    //vertices2.clear();
    //normals2.clear();
    //uves2.clear();
    printf("Loading OBJ file %s...\n", path);

    std::vector<unsigned int> vertexIndices, uvIndices, normalIndices;
    QVector<QVector3D> temp_vertices;
    QVector<QVector2D> temp_uvs;
    QVector<QVector3D> temp_normals;


    FILE * file = fopen(path, "r");
    if( file == NULL ){
        printf("Impossible to open the file ! Are you in the right path ? See Tutorial 1 for details\n");
        return false;
    }

    while( 1 ){

        char lineHeader[128];
        // read the first word of the line
        int res = fscanf(file, "%s", lineHeader);
        if (res == EOF)
            break; // EOF = End Of File. Quit the loop.

        // else : parse lineHeader

        if ( strcmp( lineHeader, "v" ) == 0 ){
            glm::vec3 vertexGLM;
            QVector3D vertex;
            fscanf(file, "%g %g %g\n", &vertexGLM.x, &vertexGLM.y, &vertexGLM.z );
            vertex.setX(vertexGLM.x);
            vertex.setY(vertexGLM.y);
            vertex.setZ(vertexGLM.z);
            temp_vertices << vertex;

        }else if ( strcmp( lineHeader, "vn" ) == 0 ){
            glm::vec3 normalGLM;
            QVector3D normal;
            fscanf(file, "%f %f %f\n", &normalGLM.x, &normalGLM.y, &normalGLM.z );
            normal.setX(normalGLM.x);
            normal.setY(normalGLM.y);
            normal.setZ(normalGLM.z);
            temp_normals << normal;
        }else if ( strcmp( lineHeader, "f" ) == 0 ){
            std::string vertex1, vertex2, vertex3;
            unsigned int vertexIndex[3], uvIndex[3], normalIndex[3];
            int matches = fscanf(file, "%d/%d/%d %d/%d/%d %d/%d/%d\n", &vertexIndex[0], &uvIndex[0], &normalIndex[0], &vertexIndex[1], &uvIndex[1], &normalIndex[1], &vertexIndex[2], &uvIndex[2], &normalIndex[2] );
            if (matches != 9){
                printf("File can't be read by our simple parser :-( Try exporting with other options\n");
                return false;
            }
            vertexIndices.push_back(vertexIndex[0]);
            vertexIndices.push_back(vertexIndex[1]);
            vertexIndices.push_back(vertexIndex[2]);

            normalIndices.push_back(normalIndex[0]);
            normalIndices.push_back(normalIndex[1]);
            normalIndices.push_back(normalIndex[2]);
        }else{
            // Probably a comment, eat up the rest of the line
            char stupidBuffer[1000];
            fgets(stupidBuffer, 1000, file);
        }

    }

    // For each vertex of each triangle
    for( unsigned int i=0; i<vertexIndices.size(); i++ ){

        vertices2 << temp_vertices[ vertexIndices[i]-1 ];
        normals2 << temp_normals[ normalIndices[i]-1 ];

        // Put the attributes in buffers


    }

    return true;
}
```

Is it possible that fscanf method make integer from float variables in some case?

```
glm::vec3 vertexGLM;
QVector3D vertex;
fscanf(file, "%g %g %g\n", &vertexGLM.x, &vertexGLM.y, &vertexGLM.z );
      vertex.setX(vertexGLM.x);
      vertex.setY(vertexGLM.y);
      vertex.setZ(vertexGLM.z);
```

When I use value 1.2345 instead of vertexGLM.x then application doesn't round it.

I could try to use another method than fscanf but do you know a reason why this function work in this way?

Comment: I don't think it's poossible that `fscanf` would ignore the fractional part of a number when asked to read a float. It's hard to be sure what's going on here. What happens if you break the debugger on the line immediately after the `fscanf`? What values do you see in `vertexGLM`?

Comment: I agree with you it's hard to be possibile. Value of `vertexGLM` after break the debugger is correctly `-2.0868  or -2.3132`. They are integers only as output of `cout()` or `printf()` so I suppose that Qt function for reading data from vector could has same problem.

Comment: When I run debugging proces without any break points everything works fine. On the otrher hand when I run application in normal mode there still are loaded integer values.

Comment: May be, a strange idea but: If this issue is a localization issue (and the decimal point is something else in your locale), it would explain why you sometimes get correct values and sometimes only the integer parts of it. In German locale, the "decimal point" is a `,`. Hence, I sometimes have this issue if I get unintendedly localization in any kind of I/O. (Unfortunately, I don't know about Polish locale but Poland is not that far away from Germany -> could be similar.) ;-)

Comment: It's not problem with just fscanf. I did it with `istringstream` and `getline`.
Again in debug mode everything is correct but when i run it normally my values are integers. And it's not problem with `, or .`

Comment: @Scheff I have to said that you are right.
In debug mode floats are readed with `.` in release with `,`. Thanks

Comment: In this case, [`setlocale()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/locale/setlocale) could be of help. e.g. `setlocale(LC_ALL, "C");` The return value can be used to restore the prior locale later. Beside of this, Qt has also encompassing locale support but I've no experience with this.